# Convergence of $\ln\frac{x}{\ln\frac{x}{\ln x...}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, closed-form, continued-fractions

I don't really know how to work with continued fractions, so I'm not too sure where to start. But this is my question: I've got a function:

$$y=\ln\frac{x}{\ln\frac{x}{\ln x...}}\tag{a}$$

I try rewriting a closed form of (a) as:

$$y=\ln{\frac{x}{y}}\tag{b}$$

When I graph this though, it seems that (a) doesn't converge to all values of (b). Specifically, when graphed, it seems that (a) diverges at around x=e. I'm not sure how to show that however, would someone be able to explain?

Comment: Exponentiate both sides to get $e^y=\frac xy$, multiply by $y$ to get $ye^y=x$, and learn about the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) ...

Comment: (This doesn't answer your questions of convergence, but it at least gives a starting point for learning a bit more about what's going on)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I appreciate the resources!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(t) = \ln(x/t)$.  For $x > 0$, the fixed point of the function $f$ is $W(x)$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  Now 
$$f'(W(x)) = -\frac{1}{W(x)}$$
This is always negative for $x>0$, and has absolute value $< 1$, implying the fixed point is stable, if and only if $x > e$.  Thus for $x > e$ it is possible that the limit is in fact $W(x)$, while for $0 < x < e$ it is not possible.

Comment: Good answer as usual :)